# Using Python to find an Excel cell value 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to find a cell value in column B in Microsoft Excel if column A's cell value is "Outstanding...". The code errors and cannot find the cell value

```
wb = Workbook()
xlfile = "ATVI.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(xlfile)
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows("A")
    for cell in row:
        #cell value you want
        if cell.value == "Shares outstanding 5":
            #change column number for any cell value you
            print(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
```

The code does work to change excel file data - example sample below, yet fails when I search within the raw data for a particular cell value, which is in a different row in each sheet. I was looking for some help while I continue my journey through this course.

Thank You,

B.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
import os
from keyboard import press
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import shutil
import math
import pandas
from decimal import Decimal
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
 
 
 
 
 
xlfile = "ATVI.xlsx"
if os.path.exists(xlfile):
    os.remove(xlfile)
 
src_file ="uk_yahoo_finance_for_stock_ATVI.xlsx"
dst_file = "ATVI.xlsx"
 
shutil.copy(src_file, dst_file)
 
wb = Workbook()
xlfile = "ATVI.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(xlfile)
 
 
#print('B3 to B5')
wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(xlfile)
 
#########################################
#########################################
 
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
 
def truncate(n, decimals=3):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return int(n * multiplier) / multiplier
 
def percentage(a, b):
    return round(a / b * 100, 2)
 
d = {
    'K': 3,
    'M': 6,
    'B': 9
    }
 
def text_to_num(text):
    if text[-1] in d:
        num, magnitude = text[:-1], text[-1]
        return Decimal(num) * 10 ** d[magnitude]
    else:
        return Decimal(text)
 
def percent2fraction(x):
    return float(x.strip('%'))/100
 
 
##########################################
#########################
 
del wb['Sheet']
wb.save(xlfile)
 
##########################################
 
blueFill = PatternFill(start_color="0D57A2", end_color="0D57A2", fill_type = "solid")
whiteFont = Font(color=colors.WHITE)
 
##########################################
"""
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[xws]
    sheet.delete_rows(74, 1)
    sheet.delete_rows(72, 1)
    sheet.delete_rows(70, 1)
    sheet.delete_rows(30, 1)
    sheet.delete_rows(28, 1)
    sheet.delete_rows(4, 1)
    sheet.delete_rows(2, 1)
wb.save(xlfile)
 
"""
##########################################
 
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[xws]
    sheet.merge_cells('A1:F1')
    sheet['A1'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A1'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A1'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.delete_rows(2,1)
    sheet.delete_rows(3,1)
    sheet['A2'] = "Period End"
    sheet['A2'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A2'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['B2'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['B2'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['C2'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['C2'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['D2'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['D2'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['E2'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['E2'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['F2'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['F2'].font = whiteFont
wb.save(xlfile)
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[xws]
    sheet.merge_cells('A6:F6')
    sheet['A6'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A6'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A16'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A16'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['B16'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['B16'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['C16'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['C16'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['D16'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['D16'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['E16'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['E16'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['F16'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['F16'].font = whiteFont
wb.save(xlfile)
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[xws] 
    sheet.merge_cells('A25:F25')
    sheet['A25'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A25'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A25'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.delete_rows(26,1)
    sheet['A26'] = "Period End"
    sheet['A26'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A26'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['B26'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['B26'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['C26'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['C26'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['D26'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['D26'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['E26'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['E26'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['F26'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['F26'].font = whiteFont
    sheet.delete_rows(27,1)
    sheet.merge_cells('A27:F27')
    sheet['A27'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A27'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A27'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.merge_cells('A47:F47')
    sheet['A47'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A47'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A47'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.merge_cells('A59:F59')
    sheet['A59'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A59'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A59'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.merge_cells('A67:F67')
    sheet['A67'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A67'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A67'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.delete_rows(68,1)
    sheet['A68'] = "Period End"
    sheet['A68'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A68'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['B68'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['B68'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['C68'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['C68'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['D68'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['D68'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['E68'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['E68'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['F68'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['F68'].font = whiteFont
wb.save(xlfile)
 
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[xws] 
    sheet.merge_cells('A70:F70')
    sheet['A70'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A70'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A70'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.merge_cells('A82:F82')
    sheet['A82'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A82'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A82'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
wb.save(xlfile)
 
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[xws] 
    sheet.merge_cells('A89:F89')
    sheet['A89'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A89'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A89'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
    sheet.merge_cells('A98:F98')
    sheet['A98'].fill = blueFill
    sheet['A98'].font = whiteFont
    sheet['A98'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
wb.save(xlfile)
 
 
 
##########################################
 
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    #print(worksheet)
    tuple(worksheet['B138':'B138'])
    for rowOfCellObjects in worksheet['B138':'B138']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            v1 = worksheet['B138'].value
            v2 = text_to_num(v1)
            v3 = truncate(v2, 0)
            cellObj.value = v3
            if cellObj.value > 0:
                cellObj.number_format = '[<999950] 0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
            elif cellObj.value == 0:
                cellObj.number_format = '[<999950] 0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
            else:
                cellObj.number_format = '[>-999950]0.0,"K";[>-999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
            cellObj.fill = PatternFill(fgColor='DFECF7', fill_type = 'solid')
            wb.save(xlfile)
            v1 = None
            v2 = None
            v3 = None
            v4 = None
##########################################
 
dash = "-"
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    tuple(worksheet['B3':'F96'])
    for rowOfCellObjects in worksheet['B3':'F96']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            cellValue = cellObj.value
            if cellValue == dash:
                cellObj.value = 0
        #print('--- END OF ROW CHANGE---')
wb.save(xlfile)
 
##########################################
 
################################
print('B3 to F5')
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    dash = "-"
    tuple(worksheet['B3':'F5'])
    for rowOfCellObjects in worksheet['B3':'F5']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            cellValue = cellObj.value
            if cellValue != dash:
                if cellValue != 0:
                    if cellValue != None:
                        x = str(cellValue)
                        y = str(x) + ",000"
                        cellObj.value = y
                        cellObj.value = cellObj.value.replace(',', '')
                        cellObj.value = int(cellObj.value)
                        wb.save(xlfile)
                        if dash not in cellValue:
                            cellObj.number_format = '[<999950] 0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
                        else:
                            cellObj.number_format = '[>-999950]0.0,"K";[>-999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
                        #
                        cellObj.value = int(float(cellObj.value))
                        #press('enter')
                    #print('--- END OF ROW CHANGE---')
wb.save(xlfile)
################################
 
######################
print('B7 to F15')
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    dash = "-"
    tuple(worksheet['B7':'F15'])
    for rowOfCellObjects in worksheet['B7':'F15']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            cellValue = cellObj.value
            if cellValue != dash:
                if cellValue != 0:
                    if cellValue != None:
                        x = str(cellValue)
                        y = str(x) + ",000"
                        cellObj.value = y
                        cellObj.value = cellObj.value.replace(',', '')
                        wb.save(xlfile)
                        if dash not in cellValue:
                            cellObj.number_format = '[<999950] 0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
                        else:
                            cellObj.number_format = '[>-999950]0.0,"K";[>-999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"'
                        #
                        cellObj.value = int(float(cellObj.value))
                        #press('enter')
                    #print('--- END OF ROW CHANGE---')
wb.save(xlfile)
```

Comment: The code which  causes the following error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

File "/Users/bhavpatel/UpworkProject/UKYahooFinance/TestCodexl/Active Vision/ATVIRunbookNew3 copy.py", line 628
for row in worksheet.iter_rows("A")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer ->

```
for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    #for row in worksheet.iter_rows("A"):
    #for row in worksheet.iter_cols("A"):
    for row in worksheet:
        for cell in row:
            #cell value you want
            if cell.value == "Shares outstanding 5":
                #change column number for any cell value you
                #x = int(worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
                #print(worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
                x = (worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
                print(x)
```